# Solving a "nearly" Hermitian linear system

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, linear-algebra, gpu

So I need to solve for the linear system (A + i * mu * I) x = b, where A is dense Hermitian matrix (6x6 complex numbers), mu is a real scalar, and I is identity matrix.

Obviously if mu=0, I should just use Cholesky and be done with it.  With non-zero mu though, the matrix ceases to be Hermitian and Cholesky fails.

Possible solutions:

1. Solve normal operator using Cholesky and multiply by the conjugate
2. Solve directly using LU decomposition

This is in a time-critical performance routine, where I need the most efficient method.  Any thoughts on the optimum approach, or if there is a specific method for solving the above shifted Hermitian system?

This is to be deployed in a CUDA kernel, where I'll be solving many linear systems in parallel, e.g., one per thread.  This means that I need a solution that minimizes thread divergence.    Given the small system size, pivoting can be ignored without too much issue: this removes a possible source of thread divergence.  I've already implemented an in-place Cholesky normal method, and while it's working ok, the performance isn't great in double precision.

Comment: Does the matrix A change over iterations? Does mu change? Is mu arbitrary (determined at run-time), or can it take only a few fixed values?

Comment: In general, A should be considered to be different for every set of calculations (I say set since I have an arrary of matrices A, and I'm doing the array processing in parallel using CUDA).  mu is indeed arbitrary and is determined at runtime.  Having said that, for a given calculation, where A is evolving, mu stays fixed over the course of the run.

Comment: You say "the performance isn't great in double precision". How is the performance using single precision? Maybe your GPU just does not have many double precision units. What GPU do you use?

Comment: The only real way to evaluate relative efficiency is to write some code and test it on real work loads. Anything else is just idle speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for the stability of the method below, but if your matrix is reasonably well conditioned, it might be worth a try.

We want to solve

```
A*X = B
```

If we pick out the first row and column, say

```
A = ( a y )
    ( z A_ )
X = ( x )
    ( X_)
B = ( b )
    ( B_ )
```

The requirement is

```
a*x + y*X_ = b
z*x + A_*X_ = B_
```

so

```
x = (b - y*X_ )/a
(A_ - zy/a) * X_ = B_ - (b/a)z
```

The solution goes in two stages. First use the second equation to transform A and b, then use the second to form the solution x.

In C:

```
static  void    nhsol( int dim, complx* A, complx* B, complx* X)
{
int i, j, k;
complx      a, fb, fa;
complx* z;
complx* acol;
    // update A and B
    for( i=0; i<dim; ++i)
    {   z = A + i*dim;
        a = z[i];
        // update B
        fb = B[i]/a;
        for( j=i+1; j<dim; ++j)
        {   B[j] -=  fb*z[j];
        }
        // update A
        for( k=i+1; k<dim; ++k)
        {   acol = A + k*dim;
            fa = acol[i]/a;
            for( j=i+1; j<dim; ++j)
            {   acol[j] -= fa*z[j];
            }
        }
    }
    // compute x
    i = dim-1;
    X[i] = B[i] / A[i+dim*i];
    while( --i>=0)
    {
    complx  s = B[i];
        for( j=i+1; j<dim; ++j)
        {   s -= A[i+j*dim]*X[j];
        }
        X[i] = s/A[i+i*dim];
    }
}
```

where

```
typedef _Complex double complx;
```

If code space is not at a premuim it might be worth unrolling the loops. Personally I would do this by writing a program whose sole job was to write the code.